# How to add a tabitem to a silverlight tabcontrol in code

Tags: silverlight, controls

This seems does not work:
  TabItem tabItem = new TabItem();
  tabItem.Header = "New tab";
  tabItem.Content = "Content";
  tabControl.Items.Add(tabItem);

Anyone has done adding TabItem dynamically to a TabControl?

Answer (score 3):

Works for me

```
TabItem item = new TabItem();
item.Header = "Test Header";
item.Content = "Some Text";

Tabs.Items.Add(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TabControl tc = new TabControl(); 
tc.Width = 400;
tc.Height = 300;

TabItem ti = new TabItem();
ti.Header = "Tab Header";
ti.Content = "Tab Content";

tc.Items.Add(ti);
LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(tc);
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(tc);
```